# My AWS RDS Oracle system account is locked

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have been working on the project by AWS RDS Oracle. But today I forgot my system account password. I continued to enter wrongly my password and the system account is now locked.

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/reset-master-user-password-rds/

Comment: thank you Chacko. I tried that method but the lock didn't solved T.T

Comment: Is `system` the master account user identifier you chose?

Comment: to Chacko Mathew
I know oracle have dba, sys, system account.
I used to system when create user.

Comment: I solve this problem. It's just my mistake. aws rds service(oracle) always lock the sys, system account
The master user and master password for that account can be set by the user himself when installing dbinstance.
I confused the oracle that was installed in the local environment and the oracle which was provided by aws.
Your answer has been a great help to me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

## In AWS RDS Oracle, you cannot access the SYSTEM account

In RDS Oracle, the SYSTEM account is open and has a password that is not known to you.
You cannot:

- find out the SYSTEM password
- change the SYSTEM password
- modify the SYSTEM account
- lock the SYSTEM account

If you try to modify SYSTEM, you get:

```
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'RDSADMIN.RDS_DDL_TRIGGER2'
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-20900: ALTER USER SYSTEM not allowed.
ORA-06512: at "RDSADMIN.RDSADMIN_TRIGGER_UTIL", line 494
```

You can access the database with DBA rights using the master account. The SYSTEM account is never the master account. In the AWS console, the default master user name is "ADMIN", but from the command line there is no default master account name.

You also cannot modify users SYS, RDSADMIN, APEX_040100, APEX_040200, the master user, RDS_DATAGUARD, AUDSYS, and XDB directly. You can change the master user password from the AWS console or from the command line.